# How to literally define an array of decimals without multiple casting?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, decimal

How can I define an array of decimals without explicitly casting each one?

```
//decimal[] prices = { 39.99, 29.99, 29.99, 19.99, 49.99 }; //can't convert double to decimal
//var prices = { 39.99, 29.99, 29.99, 19.99, 49.99 }; //can't initialize... 
decimal[] prices = { (decimal)39.99, (decimal)29.99, (decimal)29.99, (decimal)19.99, (decimal)49.99 };
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `m` suffix.

```
decimal[] prices = { 39.99m, 29.99m, 19.99m, 49.99m };
```

Without the `m` (or `M`) suffix, the compiler treats it as a double.

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 10):

You need to add [an M to the end](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A decimal literal is `39.99m`